# Lipschitz constant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am studying the Lipschitz continuity and trying to solve the following question:

If a function $f(x)= Ax$ is defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $A= \begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    c       & d
\end{bmatrix}$, then find a constant L such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
||Ax - Ay|| \le L||x - y||, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
I understand how to find the Lipschitz constant in $\mathbb{R}$, but I have no idea about how to find it in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Presumably, you want a constant $L$ such that $\| Ax_{1} -Ax_{2}\| \leq L \| x_{1}-x_{2} \|$, right?  What do you know about the norm of the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2):

The Lipschitz constant $L$ for the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is given by its Spectral norm $\sigma(\boldsymbol{A})$.

Spectral norm is the maximum singular value (from [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) of the matrix, i.e. maximum scaling of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

For the Frobenius norm, given by $\mid\mid A\mid\mid=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\mid a_{ij}\mid^2}$.

we get $\mid\mid Ax_1-Ax_2\mid\mid\le\mid\mid A\mid\mid\cdot\mid\mid x_1-x_2\mid\mid\le2\operatorname{max}\{\mid a\mid,\mid b\mid,\mid c\mid,\mid d\mid\}\mid\mid x_1-x_2\mid\mid$.